# Add and update column / create new table with the additional row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update, alter-table

I have two huge tables with 10 million rows in table A and 2.5 million rows in table B. Both tables have a common field id. Table A has ~250 columns and table B has 5 columns. All the ids in table B are present in table A. I want to add a field (in date format) in table A to table B. I have two options, and both are taking lot of time to run. I want to know which will be efficient.

**Option 1:**
`alter table B add column field date;`
`update B join A using(id) set a.field=b.field;`

**Option 2:**
`create table C as select a.*,b.field from B join A using(id);`

`id` is indexed in both the tables and ENGINE is MyISAM.

Which option will be faster?

I think 2 because in option 1, adding a column is taking time, then while updating, lot of time is taken for the state `copy to tmp table`. In option 1, it straight away starts with the state 'Sending data'. Am I correct?

Also, can I do this in any other faster way?

Comment: Option 2 will be more suitable in this scenario.

Comment: i think im missing something... but, you whant to move a date colum from A to B ? if thats right, may i ask wy u whant do it ?

Comment: @Melon For the ids in B, I need to get the field (which is in date format) from A. I need it only for the ids in B which I will put into a csv for some other purpose.

Comment: i think you already discard a view option: `CREATE  VIEW 'my_view' as select * from B join A on B.id = A.id;` so yo could run : `select field,any_field from my_view`. if the "field" its suitable to change hav it replicated in a database its a bad option. (unles to make a trigger to keep it updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only whant to select information you can create a view to get all the data together

```
CREATE VIEW 'my_view' as select * from B join A on B.id = A.id;
```

so you can run

```
select field,any_field from my_view where any_condition;
```

having duplicated data in a database is absolutly unrecommend

i hope this help you. sice it isnt any of your options.

---

you can also run the query itself

```
 select  field,any_field from B join A on B.id = A.id where any_condition;
```